# MySQL recursion depth resets to 0 in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, stored-procedures

Basically I have a recursive stored procedure in my database.
Now, while creating it I put `SET max_sp_recursion_depth=100;` right before the `CREATE PROCEDURE` line and then calling the procedure works fine.

Now I am trying to call that procedure by nodejs using the `npm-mysql` module.

But when I now call it, it shows the error `Recursive limit 0 (as set by the max_sp_recursion_depth variable) was exceeded for routine insertStation` even though the procedure is already created in the database along with setting its configuration.

The code that I used is
`con.query("CALL insertMain('A','J')");`

Then, I noticed that while I restart the MySQl server, I usually have to create the procedure again because it automatically resets to 0 recursion depth. But I can't afford to create the procedure again and again everytime (have to integrate nodejs to website).

So, is there a way to permanentally change the recursion depth OR pass the configuration along with the nodejs query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just found out that `con.query("SET max_sp_recursion_depth=100;");` does the job.